# ionic cli: all commands giving error undefined:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework

I have downloaded and installed `nodejs` (setup file `node-v0.12.5-x64`) in my Windows7 pc.
Also installed ionic via command: **`npm install -g ionic cordova`**

All ionic commands are giving same error i.e. **`undefined:1`**.
In command prompt it looks like below:

```
E:\programs>ionic -v  
undefined:1  
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

I am not able to resolve after many installation and un-installation.
Please help.

Comment: are you running ionic in node? cause you cant run ionic in node

Comment: is there any alternate to run ionic directly?

Comment: yeah once you have it installed you just run it directly from the command line, Not from the node command line

Comment: I have found a solution, answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32864879/1276616

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue on another thread

My C:\Users\USER\ .ionic\ionic.config had been corrupted and deleting it solved the issue

if that's not the issue then navigate to where you have ionic installed, for me it's
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic

then open a command prompt and run "npm install -g node-debug
after installing run "node-debug app.js" from that folder and step through the program to identify the error